# How can I add values to a type to be able to do a database fragmentation based on it?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

Lets say that I create the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(COLUMN1 INT NOT NULL,
COLUMN2 myType NOT NULL);
```

I want to create a type named myType, that can only have 4 values, for example "blue" , "white" , "green" and "red".

Should I create it like this :

```
CREATE TYPE myType AS OBJECT
( 
name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

and then fill it with those values  :

```
INSERT INTO myType (name)
VALUES ("blue", "red", "green" , "white");
```

If I do that, and I want to insert values into the table MYTABLE, how can I specify which type I want to select? 
And will I be able to do a horizontal fragmentation of MYTABLE based on the 4 values of that myType?

Comment: Why not just use a check constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use a type? A simple column would suffice, with a CHECK CONSTRAINT to enforce those values:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(COLUMN1 INT NOT NULL,
    COLUMN2 varchar2(10) NOT NULL
    check (column2 in (('blue', 'red', 'green' , white'))
);
```

> " will I be able to do a horizontal fragmentation of MYTABLE"

Yes.

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(COLUMN1 INT NOT NULL,
    COLUMN2 varchar2(10) NOT NULL
    check (column2 in ('blue', 'red', 'green' , 'white'))
)
 partition by list (column2) 
 (
     partition p_blue
        values ('blue' )
    , partition p_red
        values ('red')
    , partition p_green
        values ('green')
    , partition p_white
        values ('white')
);
```